# Immediately updating a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have an application that checks a number of 7zip arhive if they are not corrupt, and I want to write every action in a listbox, but my problem is that the listbox doesn't display each line when I add an item to it, it updates at finish, and puts all the items at the end of my action even if I use the property .StartUpdate() and EndUpdate()

This is a part of my code:

```
foreach (string director in foldere)
{
    if (director.ToLower().Contains("cluj") || director.ToLower().Contains("craiova") || director.ToLower().Contains("timisoara"))
    {
        String[] zipFile = Directory.GetFiles(director, "*.7z");
        foreach (string zip7 in zipFile)
        {
            //check arhive
            SevenZipExtractor zipfile = new SevenZipExtractor(zip7);
            if (zipfile.Check())
            {
                String[] fisFaraArhiva = Directory.GetFiles(director, "*.*");
                foreach (string fisere in fisFaraArhiva)
                {
                    if (fisere != zip7)
                    {
                        File.Delete(fisere);
                    }
                }
                listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "A fost sters fisierele din directorul " + director);
                string[] fisComanda = Directory.GetFiles(utilizator, "*" + id + "*");
                foreach (string cmd in fisComanda)
                {
                    File.Move(cmd, Path.Combine(director, Path.GetFileName(cmd)));
                    listBox1.BeginUpdate();
                    listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "A fost mutata comanda " + Path.GetFileName(cmd) + " in director");
                    listBox1.EndUpdate();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Arhiva nu este ok");
                listBox1.BeginUpdate();
                listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Arhiva " + zip7 + " NU este OK");
                listBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                listBox1.EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
if (listBox1.BackColor != Color.Red)
{
    listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    listBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling `listBox1.Update()` after inserting an item:

```
listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "A fost mutata comanda " + Path.GetFileName(cmd) + " in director");
listBox1.Update();
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the User Interface will get updated when the UI thread has time to do it but you are claiming the UI Thread. There are two ways to solve that:

1. Use listBox1.Update() to force the update of the UI or
2. Use a background thread (BackgroundWorker) to do the processing and have it report its progress to the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

After you insert anything in your list, call `Update()` on the list. This will force the update.

So instead of

```
listBox1.BeginUpdate();
listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "A fost mutata comanda " + Path.GetFileName(cmd) + " in director");
listBox1.EndUpdate();
```

do

```
listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "A fost mutata comanda " + Path.GetFileName(cmd) + " in director");
listBox1.Update();
```